# Unable configure SQL Server reporting service 2017

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2017

I'm getting a typical error, never faced before.

I'm unable to install, un-install or repair

```
            Setting string variable 'InstallFolder' to value 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services'
             Setting string variable 'SKU' to value 'SsrsEvaluation'
            UnexpectedError: Current security context is not associated with an Active Directory domain or forest.
            User: Bundle action completed with errors, please fix the issue then try repair.
            UnexpectedError: Burn engine encountered error. PackageId: SSReportingServicesSetup.msi, ErrorType: WindowsInstaller, ErrorCode: -2147483648, Data: , ErrorMessage: Something went wrong, please find details in setup logs.CallStack:
            Unhandled Exception: System.Exception: XmlException -    at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
               at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
               at System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean preserveWhitespace)
               at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
               at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(String filename)
               at Microsoft.BIServer.Setup.MigrateSettingsStep.MigrateMachineKeyFromWebToRsConfig()
               at SetupEngine.Install()
               at SetupEngine.Execute()
               at Microsoft.BIServer.Setup.Setup.Main(String cmdLine)
               at Microsoft.BIServer.Setup.Setup.Main(String cmdLine)
            , UIHint: 0
            User: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services: Something went wrong, please find details in setup logs.
            UnexpectedError: setup failed for packageId: SSReportingServicesSetup.msi, package: Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services, errorCode: -2147483648, errorMessage: Something went wrong, please find details in setup logs.
            Setup: Repair Completed for package Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services
             Applied execute package: SSReportingServicesSetup.msi, result: 0x0, restart: None
             Registering dependency: {21dc2411-ec49-43f5-a195-4dcd848b0f84} on package provider: {7E3B2275-82E0-4969-A38D-544F5C360F12}, package: SSReportingServicesSetup.msi
            Setup: Package action completed.
             Setup: A restart is required.
             Condition 'RebootPending = 1' evaluates to false.
             User: Bundle action completed with errors, please fix the issue then try repair.
Migrating machine key from ReportServer C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services\SSRS\ReportServer\web.config to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services\SSRS\ReportServer\rsreportserver.config
    Install Step Microsoft.BIServer.Setup.MigrateSettingsStep threw exception. System.Xml.XmlException: Root element is missing.
       at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
       at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
       at System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean preserveWhitespace)
       at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
       at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(String filename)
       at Microsoft.BIServer.Setup.MigrateSettingsStep.MigrateMachineKeyFromWebToRsConfig()
       at SetupEngine.Install()
 Install Microsoft.BIServer.Setup.MigrateSettingsStep | END 
    Setup FailedSystem.Xml.XmlException: Root element is missing.
       at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
       at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
       at System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean preserveWhitespace)
       at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
       at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(String filename)
       at Microsoft.BIServer.Setup.MigrateSettingsStep.MigrateMachineKeyFromWebToRsConfig()
       at SetupEngine.Install()
       at SetupEngine.Execute()
       at Microsoft.BIServer.Setup.Setup.Main(String[] cmdLine)
```

What could be the issue? How to resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delete this folder:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services

Comment: Thanks for clue. Will try and mark as answer. Looking like MS needs lots of improvements.

Answer (score 0):

I looked everywhere for this solution.  Deleting the above folder did the trick, followed by running the repair option from SQLServerReportingServices.exe (run as administrator).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31902253)